# Find the position (X,Y) neighbors in a Matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

Given a 4x4 matrix. I want to find the 4-neighbors of a given position

```
(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3)
(1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3)
(2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3)
(3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)
```

Example:
If I want to find the 4-neighbors of position (2,2), it should return

```
(1,2), (3,2), (2,1), (2,3)
```

Comment: what about the edge items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def get_neighbors(x, y):
    return (x - 1, y),  (x + 1, y), (x, y -1), (x, y + 1)

print(get_neighbors(2, 2))
# ((1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3))

print(*get_neighbors(2, 2))  # if you want them single, unpack it
# (1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3)
```